Terraform and Azure pipelines - authorize pipelines in a service connection
In azure devops pipelines I have a service connection for a docker container registry. Whenever I create a pipelines I allow the pipelines to use this service connections from:
project settings > Service connection > Container registry > security > Pipeline permissions
As per the following image:

How to modify the below terraform config to add permission to access a given service connection?
resource "azuredevops_build_definition" "project" {
  project_id = "xxx"
  name       = "xxx"
  path       = "\\"


  repository {
    repo_type             = "xxx"
    repo_id               = "xxx"
    branch_name           = "xxx"
    yml_path              = "azure-pipelines.yml"
    service_connection_id = "xxx"
  }
}


Had to use terraform's azuredevops_pipeline_authorization

resource "azuredevops_build_definition" "project" {
  project_id = "xxx"
  name       = "xxx"
  path       = "\\"


  repository {
    repo_type             = "xxx"
    repo_id               = "xxx"
    branch_name           = "xxx"
    yml_path              = "azure-pipelines.yml"
    service_connection_id = "xxx"
  }
}

resource "azuredevops_pipeline_authorization" "acr" {
  project_id  = "xxx"
  resource_id = "xxx"  # ID of service connection
  type        = "endpoint"
  pipeline_id = azuredevops_build_definition.example.id
}

